# Objective-c NSMutableArray of Objects retain

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nsmutablearray, retain

I just can't get it! I have custom class "Word" also I generate NSMutableArray of Word-class-objects in few steps:

1. words = [NSMutableArray array];
2. for i = 0 to 8
3. word = alloc+init;
4. [words addObject: word];
5. [word release];

Then I pass words instance to setter of another class:

```
someInstance.words = words;
```

Where words is nonatomic, retain property. I declare setWords method like this:

```
-(void)setWords:(NSMutableArray *)w {
    [w retain];
    [words release];
    words = w;
}
```

When words come to method as "w" variable it is an array of object but when I retain it and assign to my old value my words variable becomes an NSMUtableArray and it count is equal to w.count, but items of array 0x0. The "=" operator does not copy items of array, how can I fix it? Please help, I am a newbie in objective-c.
I instanciate Word only with one method, shoud I implement parameterless init method?

```
-(id)initWithId:(int)Id Word:(NSString *)Word Card:(int)Card {
    self.id = Id;
    self.word = Word;
    self.card = Card;
    return self;
}
```

The cycle where I generate my NSMutableArray:

```
Card *card = [[Card alloc] initWithId:[s intForColumn:@"id"] Type:[s intForColumn:@"type"] Used:[s intForColumn:@"used"]];
s = [db executeQueryWithFormat:@"SELECT w.id as id, word, card FROM word as w INNER JOIN card as c ON w.card=c.id WHERE c.id=%i ORDER BY w.id, RANDOM()", card.id];
while ([s next]) {
    Word *word = [[Word alloc] initWithId:[s intForColumn:@"id"] Word:[s stringForColumn:@"word"] Card:[s intForColumn:@"card"]];
    [card.words addObject:word];
    [word release];
}
```

Comment: To understand you can look at screenshot I was not able to insert it in the post because of small reputation: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UheIk.png

Comment: Show us your subclass init method.

Comment: Another idea is to use `words = [w mutableCopy]` in your setter method.

Comment: Can you please add the exact code you use to create this array before passing it to the setter?

Comment: Do you modify the array in any way after assigning it to the property?

Comment: Oh and one more thing. Your `retain` on the property declaration is irrelevant because you are overwriting the setter anyway.

Comment: @Rog: Not completely irrelevant; it still documents the behavior of the setter.

Comment: can you also add your .h def of words?

Comment: You're missing a super constructor. See my answer.

Comment: @Rog: but if I remove retain keyword I get a warning: assign property attribute not appropriate for non-gc object (

Comment: @H2CO3 I do as you say, but still get an array of NULL

Comment: @Rog [w mutableCopy] working like [w retain] - it gives me an array of NULL 0x0

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems w/your code.

- you need to follow the standard initialization pattern of calling super's designated initializer and checking the return value.
- That method should be named `initWithId:word:card:` (i.e. case is wrong, hence the goofy coloring on StackOverflow, even).
- There is no need to implement a custom setter/getter if your setter/getter just follow the standard pattern.  Use an @property and @synthesize.
- (from your screenshot) you really don't want to be directly triggering UI updates from your setter.   Generally, anyway.   Generally, you want your view layer to trigger an update of your model through the control and, once the model is fully updated, then let the view layer know it should reload.
- While you mention that you are instantiating an NSMutableArray instance, you don't show that in your code.   Is `card.words` really set when you are adding `Word` instances?

Show the -initWithId:card:type:used: (note I corrected the case) method's implementation.

I.e. it better had have something like:

```
 words = [NSMutableArray new]; // Or, if ARC, [NSMutableArray array];
```

---

OK -- next...

- put an `assert(card.words);` before your `while()` loop... that'll blow up if `words` isn't set.
- make sure that the `card` is non-nil (no reason why it shouldn't but... when the obvious stuff looks right, you check the *really* obvious stuff next)

The comment about -reloadData is more that you would want to `reloadData` in whatever triggers the loading in the first place.  Imagine a situation where you are loading several different kinds of data prior to updating the whole UI;  maybe the table view has to be reloaded *and* some other stuff needs to be updated around it.  By moving the `reloadData` out of the setter it (a) makes the setter simple and non-surprising while (b) makes it easier to refactor your UI layer such that multi-UI element updating can be done simultaneously.

(Also -- please don't take my comments about coding style harshly...  not meant to be... there are some subtle, but universal patterns to Obj-C coding.  If you learn them and use them, it'll make your life a lot easier.   We were all new to Obj-C once.  Just that some of us were new to it while others of your weren't even born yet. ;).

Comment: -(id)initWithId:(int)i type:(int)t used:(int)u {
    self.id = i;
    self.type = t;
    self.used = u;
    self.words  = [NSMutableArray array];
    return self;
}

Comment: 1. I fixed it
2. Okay, my mistake, corrected
3. But I also want to execute [tableView reloadData] method
4. tableView is an UITableView, words is my data to fill table cells, isn't it nessesary to call reloadData when I update datasource?
5. Look prev comment

Comment: I make my assign working just removed @synthesize words statement and added NSMutableArray *words_, but now I can't make my tablwview updates with new datasource, even [tableView reloadData] not working =(